# Change div class to Active once clicked or Deactive if clicked again

Tags: javascript

When I click my link the div changes to active and ajax is loaded.
But how can I then say if the link is clicked again that it should become deactive?

```
favourite.onclick = function() {     
        loadXMLDoc('indexFavourite'); 
        favourite.className = 'statusOptionActive'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
favourite.onclick = function() {     
        loadXMLDoc('indexFavourite'); 
        var linkclass = favourite.className;
        if(linkclass == 'statusOptionDeactive')
            favourite.className = 'statusOptionActive';
        else
            favourite.className = 'statusOptionDeactive';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
favourite.className = (favourite.className == 'statusOptionActive') ? 'statusOptionDeactive' : 'statusOptionActive';
```

The above checks if the current `className` is `statusOptionActive`. If yes, it changes the `className` to `statusOptionDeactive`. If no, it sets it as `statusOptionActive`.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/FH7NW/)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a global variable like:

```
var isDivActive = false;
```

Which is false by default.

```
favourite.onclick = function() {
    loadXMLDoc('indexFavourite');

    if (isDivActive) {
        favourite.className = 'statusOptionActive';
    }
    else {
        favourite.className = '';
    }

    isDivActive = !isDivActive;
}
```